# help me to migrate single myslq5.6 server to mysql5.6 Cluster, follow this error!

Tags: mysql-5.6

I try to migrate a single myslq5.6 server to mysql5.6 Cluster. I do not understand why I get the follow this error:

> ERROR 1297 (HY000) at line 1 in file: 'load_dept_emp.dump': Got temporary error 233 'Out of operation records in transaction coordinator (increase MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations)' from NDBCLUSTER

Comment: What OS? What did  you do?

Comment: redhat6.5. we olny migrated single mysql db to cluster mysql db (community), if we migrated innodb tables to sql query servers is ok, but to ndb servers is bad, it's reason why mysql cluster is community ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, i have just found a way to slove my question. follow here:

1.you must configure the config.ini file in your MGM nodes

/opt/mysql-cluster/etc/config.ini

Setting this parameter of "MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions" a bigger value

2.if you reconfigure config.ini, you must delete this file of ndb_2_config.bin.1, and then restart MGM Services

ndb_2_config.bin.1 is a cache and binary file

3.in fact, if you recofingure confing.ini, you can use "# ndb_mgmd --ndb_nodeid=1 --initial -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini" for updating ndb_2_config.bin.1 effective.

try it!